# Rails deployment not showing images on the production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, nginx, asset-pipeline

I am using AWS Opswork for the deployment of my rails app

i am using unicorn + Nginx and I am stuck into this error since 2 days , my application is working fine and i got my css and javascript working after doing rake assets:precompile but i am not able to see any image or fa icon in my application

all my images are stored in app/assets/images

and in the html views i am using it like `<img src="/assets/image.jpg">`

my images are loading perfectly in the development but not in the production

Answer (score 8):

I had this issue. I had to recompile my assets.

1. Remove previously pre-compiled assets by runnning `rake assets:clobber`
2. Pre-compile `rake assets:precompile`
3. Restart your application / server

Hope this helps

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that your `production.rb` settings include:

```
# Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
config.serve_static_assets = false

# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
config.assets.compile = false

# Generate digests for assets URLs
config.assets.digest = true
```

This is how you can precompile assets with SCSS:

```
#application.css.scss (yes, you need to rename it)
@import 'layout/body'


#app/assets/stylesheets/layout/body.css.scss
body {
    background: asset_url('image.jpg')
}
```

When you do the above, make sure you precompile like this:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: i just did rake assets:precompile by logging in the aws instance by ssh

Comment: but my css and javascripts are working fine , does the command you suggested will get my images work ?

Comment: @user4965201 Yes it should work. Make sure you precompile assets as suggested above and be sure to run `sudo service unicorn restart` after that.

Comment: i am getting saas syntax error in precompiling , as i have large no. of css files can i get this command work without getting syntax error in css ?
also i am not able to find file where i got the syntax error

Comment: could you please provide the error you are getting ?

Comment: @user4965201 I have edited my answer. Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97949/discussion-between-user4965201-and-dusht).

Answer (score 0):

Just write image tag in rails way not html way like :

```
image_tag("icon.png")
# => <img alt="Icon" src="/assets/icon.png" />
image_tag("icon.png", size: "16x10", alt: "Edit Entry")
# => <img src="/assets/icon.png" width="16" height="10" alt="Edit Entry" />
```

`rake assets:precompile` generate assets into public folder of application and fetch (precompiled image,css,js) from public/assets folder.

Comment: but how can i do this in css files

Comment: no need to change in css, rails precompile css file and map images from public/assets folder